# Register Mapping for all other mappings

Tags: mapstruct

Is there a way to register a Mapper definition globally to all the other Mappers, **without having to add anything to each Mapper**?

Here is our problem : we have had a bug on our project due the way objects of java.util.Date type are handled by default in mappers: they are copied from the source to the target, thus making them shared. As a result, we sometime inadvertently modified the source data while modifying the target data.
Our solution was to create a mapper for Dates (that instantiates a new Date for the target), and to add it to all our Mappers using:

```
@Mapper(uses= {DateMapper.class, ...})
```

Our problem now is that any developper that forget to add the DateMapper to a new Mapper will cause the bug to happen again. A way to register it globally would be more secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this moment (1.2.0.Final and 1.3.0.Beta1) this can be achieved by using [Shared Configurations](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#shared-configurations). With `@MapperConfig` you can define a common configuration and then use that in your mappers (yes people will need to not forget to include that via `@Mapper#config`).

If this is not sufficient I would suggest creating an issue in the MapStruct [issue tracker](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/)